# Chatbots in Salesforce communities

Tags: customer-community, einstein

Is there anyway we can use Einstein Agents (chatbots) in Salesforce communities?

I have googled around and could not find any.

Answer (score 1):

Einstein bots are significant from Service Management perspective. And that you can always use Communities for Service Management, you definitely can have Einstein bots in Salesforce Communities.

If you refer to the [Einstein Bots Requirements](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bots_service_requirements.htm&type=5), setting up Community in fact seems to be a required step to be able to use the bots.

Thus to answer to your question - Yes, you can use it with Community based on the information available in documentation.

Excerpt below from the help article:

> Before we can have fun with Einstein Bots, we have to finish a few chores.
>
> 1. Obtain a Service Cloud license and a Live Agent license. Each org is provided with 25 Einstein Bots conversations per month for each Live Agent User with an active subscription. To make full use of the Einstein Bots Performance page, obtain the Service Analytics App.
> 2. Enable Lightning Experience.
> 3. Run the Live Agent guided setup flow.
> 4. Enable Salesforce Knowledge if your Einstein Bot serves Knowledge articles to customers.
> 5. Publish a **Salesforce community** (preferable) or a Lightning Platform site.
> 6. Provide a Snap-ins chat button for your customers on your **community** or site.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Jayant Das, much appreciated :)

Comment: I hope this information is helpful, as it was for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Bob,

Einstein Bots are available with Service Cloud and hence they can also be setup with a Community. Although, Bots are more contextual for anonymous user queries. Here are a few links that can help you understand and setup an Einstein Bot as well as a [Trailhead Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/service_bots_basics) for some hands-on.

[The Magic of Einstein Bot](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/11/the-magic-of-einstein-bot.html)

[Summer'18 Einstein Bots for People](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/06/summer18-einstein-bots-for-the-people.html)

[How to Setup Einstein Bots in a few Easy Steps](https://www.salesforce.com/video/1756700/)